# Why does Azure Cognitive Services SDK Speech-to-Text stop unexpectedly inside of WCF service?

Tags: web-services, wcf, sdk, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I'm calling out to a Windows Communication Foundation(WCF) service with a asynchronous call from the client to kick off a Azure Cognitive Speech Service SDK (`using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech`) instance of `SpeechRecognizer`. The Speech Recognizer takes two arguments;

```
SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(key, region)
```

and

```
AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(fileName)
```

When the client calls the WCF in a development environment (localhost), `SpeechRecognizer` is able to recognize audio files of more than 120 minutes in length, successfully returning our `RecognizedSpeech` text results.

When the WCF service is deployed as a WCF Based Azure Cloud Service, `SpeechRecognizer` for audio files of length greater than 9 minutes seem to never enter:

```
recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) => {}
```

It appears there is no error being caught, nor no error being thrown by `SpeechRecognizer`. The Service seems to stop "listening" to the audio input unexpectedly.

I have tried increasing the WCF Service's `<basicHttpBinding />`'s `<binding />` `Timeout` variables to one hour, as well as increasing the `BufferSize` variables to `2GB`. No luck.

I am now questioning if i should have ever put this functionality inside of a WCF service at all...

I will provide more information as necessary! Thanks.

---

### Update

I was able to solve this issue by extracting the Azure Cognitive Speech Service from the WCF service and into a console application(.exe). After going down this path, I recommend using a message queue inside a web service to kick off a Cognitive Service living elsewhere or simply introduce Azure Cognitive Speech Service into the client. I don't recommend my solution, hard to debug and test in production environments (only logs).

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow!  Is your question whether you should put this in a WCF or why it stopped unexpectedly?